# How to specify variable padding for tikz node text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a custom tikz node with a design along the top and left side, and would like to center its text in the bottom-right section of the node.  For example, I would like to center the text in section `D` of the node, below:

```
+---+-----------+
| A |     C     |
+---+-----------+
|   |           |
|   |           |
| B |     D     |
|   |           |
|   |           |
+---+-----------+
```

Using the option, `text centered`, causes it to be centered with respect to the whole shape, not just section `D`.  How may I center it with respect to the bounds of just `D`?  In HTML I could use the options, `padding-left` and `padding-top`, but I haven't been able to find comparable options for tikz nodes.

Edit: This is what I have so far:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{makeshape}

\usetikzlibrary{
  automata,
  shadows.blur,
}

\makeatletter
\def\band{10pt}
\def\internalstorageAnchorpath{
   \pgf@xa=\ctbnex
   \pgf@ya=\ctbney
   \advance\pgf@xa by \band
   \advance\pgf@ya by \band
   \mincorrect{\pgf@xa}{\pgfshapeminwidth}
   \advance\pgf@xa\pgfshapeouterxsep
   \mincorrect{\pgf@ya}{\pgfshapeminheight}
   \advance\pgf@ya\pgfshapeouterysep
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{-\pgf@ya}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xa}{-\pgf@ya}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
   \pgfpathclose
}
\def\internalstorageBackground{
   \pgf@xa=\ctbnex
   \pgf@ya=\ctbney
   \advance\pgf@xa by \band
   \advance\pgf@ya by \band
   \mincorrect{\pgf@xa}{\pgfshapeminwidth}
   \mincorrect{\pgf@ya}{\pgfshapeminheight}
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{-\pgf@ya}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xa}{-\pgf@ya}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
   \pgfpathclose
   \advance\pgf@xa by -\band
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xa}{-\pgf@ya}}
   \advance\pgf@xa by \band
   \advance\pgf@ya by -\band
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
}
\pgfdeclareshape{internalstorage}{
   \setpaths{\internalstorageAnchorpath}{\internalstorageBackground}
   \savedanchor{\northeast}{
      \pgf@x = \ctbnex
      \advance\pgf@x by \band
      \mincorrect{\pgf@x}{\pgfshapeminwidth}
      \advance\pgf@x\pgfshapeouterxsep
      \pgf@y = \ctbney
      \mincorrect{\pgf@y}{\pgfshapeminheight}
      \advance\pgf@y\pgfshapeouterysep
   }
   \anchor{north}{ \northeast \pgf@x=0pt }
   \anchor{north east}{ \northeast }
   \anchor{east}{ \northeast \pgf@y=0pt }
   \anchor{south east}{ \northeast \pgf@y=-\pgf@y }
   \anchor{south}{ \northeast \pgf@x=0pt \pgf@y=-\pgf@y }
   \anchor{south west}{ \northeast \pgf@x=-\pgf@x \pgf@y=-\pgf@y }
   \anchor{west}{ \northeast \pgf@x=-\pgf@x \pgf@y=0pt }
   \anchor{north west}{ \northeast \pgf@x=-\pgf@x }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    >=stealth,
    every state/.style={
      font=\small,
      blur shadow,
      thick,
    },
    internal storage/.style={
      state,
      internalstorage,
      text width=5em,
      text centered,
      top color=BlueViolet!60,
      bottom color=BlueViolet!20,
    },
  ]
  \node[state, internal storage, text centered] {foo bar baz qux quux quo};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The generated node looks like the following:

[image: internal storage]

As you can see, the alignment of the text looks funny because it isn't centered with respect to the decorations.

Comment: No, I'm trying to center text within a section of a custom node.  As far as I know, the matrix library is only useful for aligning nodes with respect to each other.

Comment: With node labels, you can specify `shift` offsets.  I'm looking for something equivalent for node contents.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What have you tried? Can you please post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) with your "custom code" so that we have something to work from. In additional to making it much easier for people to help you, a MWE will also help to clarify what you want. A MWE should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Updated.  Please review my post again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could draw `internalstorage` node as a regular one, but place its contents using a `label` node on its lower right corner. If you fixes label's size and outer node's size and know the difference between them, you can draw internal lines with `path picture` options which survives to a `fill` option. These nodes are compatible with `matrix`.

This is an example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    internalstorage/.style={%
        minimum size=2.5cm,
        draw,
        thick,
        text width=5em,
        top color=purple!60,
        bottom color=purple!20,
        label={[minimum size=2cm,
                text width=5em,
                font=\small,
                text centered,
                anchor=south east]
                south east:#1
        },
        path picture={
            \draw ([xshift=5mm]path picture bounding box.south west)--([xshift=5mm]path picture bounding box.north west);
            \draw ([yshift=-5mm]path picture bounding box.north west)--([yshift=-5mm]path picture bounding box.north east);
        }
    }
]

\matrix[row sep=1mm, column sep=1mm] (a) {
\node[internalstorage=foo bar baz qux quux quo] {};
&
\node[internalstorage=foo] {};
\\
\node[internalstorage=foo bar baz] {};
&
\node[internalstorage=foo bar baz qux quux] {};
\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks amazing, but I cannot get your example to work.  If I remove the styling on the label it works but the label is then placed on the outside of the node to the south east.  Do you have a special set up that lets it work?

Comment: @Dylon I'm not sure to understand the problem. The styling on the label makes it works, you need to place south east anchor of label on south east anchor of main node to obtain the special alignment. What do you want to avoid from label style?

Comment: I figured it out: I placed a newline between the opening square bracket in the label style and `minimum size`, which caused the parser to err.  Removing it resolved the issue.  This is great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations to your nice example! But I still keep advertizing `matrix`.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[row 1 column 1/.style={align=left},
row 1 column 2/.style={align=right,text width=4em},
row 2 column 1/.style={align=left},
row 2 column 2/.style={text centered,text width=5em},
every node/.append style={draw},column sep=-\pgflinewidth,row
sep=-\pgflinewidth,]

\matrix[matrix of nodes,draw,top color=BlueViolet!60,
      bottom color=BlueViolet!20,inner sep=0pt,nodes={draw=none,inner sep=4pt}] (mat)
  {
   A & B\\
    C & foo bar baz qux quux quo\\
  };
\path ($(mat-1-1.east)!0.5!(mat-1-2.west)$) coordinate (aux1)
($(mat-1-1.south)!0.5!(mat-2-1.north)$) coordinate (aux2);
\draw (mat.north -| aux1) -- (mat.south -| aux1)
(mat.west |- aux2) -- (mat.east |- aux2) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a quick attempt to define a style. My first attempt to draw the separator lines with `append after command` did not succeed, so I added a command for that (temporarily).

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{fancy matrix/.style={row 1 column 1/.style={align=left},
row 1 column 2/.style={align=right,text width=4em},
row 2 column 1/.style={align=left},
row 2 column 2/.style={text centered,text width=5em},
matrix of nodes,draw,top color=BlueViolet!60,
bottom color=BlueViolet!20,inner sep=0pt,nodes={draw=none,inner sep=4pt},
append after command={}
}}
\newcommand{\DrawMatrixSeparators}[2][]{
\draw[#1] ($(#2-1-1.east)!0.5!(#2-1-2.west)$) coordinate (aux1)
($(#2-1-1.south)!0.5!(#2-2-1.north)$) coordinate (aux2)
(#2.north -| aux1) -- (#2.south -| aux1)
(#2.west |- aux2) -- (#2.east |- aux2);}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\matrix[fancy matrix] (mat)
  {
   A & B\\
    C & foo bar baz qux quux quo\\
  };
\DrawMatrixSeparators{mat}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have a problem with node alignment, but text alignment within a node.

Comment: Please review my original post again.  I've updated it with more information.

Comment: Is the `foo...` text centered in the lower right area? Looks like closer to left margin than right one.

Comment: @Sigur Yes, there was an asymmetry cause by the `inner sep` of the ambient matrix node. I was actually already fixing this when I saw your comment, but yes, good catch thanks!

Comment: The "internal storage" node is for a flowchart, is there a way I can draw it using a matrix internally?  I'd like to reuse it in other places.

Comment: I'm creating flowchart shapes and this is one of them.  I would need to reproduce this shape for every `internal storage` node of my flowchart.  I am using a matrix for the flowchart.

Comment: How would I move the matrix into a style?

Comment: @Dylon I added a style for the matrix (or gave you a start, I think one can make that more elegant). Whether or not one can nest matrices, I do not know out of the top of my head. But honestly I do not know if there is another simple option. Of course you can always define your own shape, as you tried to do. The fact that you are asking the question seem to indicate that this has complications.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but isn't perfect. I'll revise it as I strengthen my tikz fu.

[image]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makeshape}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usetikzlibrary{
  automata,
  matrix,
  shadows.blur,
}

\begin{document}

\def\padding{10pt}

\makeatletter
\def\internalStorageAnchorPath{
   \pgf@xa=\ctbnex
   \pgf@ya=\ctbney
   \mincorrect{\pgf@xa}{\pgfshapeminwidth}
   \advance\pgf@xa\pgfshapeouterxsep
   \mincorrect{\pgf@ya}{\pgfshapeminheight}
   \advance\pgf@ya\pgfshapeouterysep
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{-\pgf@ya}}
   \advance\pgf@xa by \padding
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xa}{-\pgf@ya}}
   \advance\pgf@ya by \padding
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
   \advance\pgf@xa by -\padding
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
   \pgfpathclose
}
\def\internalStorageBackgroundPath{
   \pgf@xa=\ctbnex
   \pgf@ya=\ctbney
   \mincorrect{\pgf@xa}{\pgfshapeminwidth}
   \mincorrect{\pgf@ya}{\pgfshapeminheight}
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{-\pgf@ya}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xa}{-\pgf@ya}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
   \pgfpathclose
}
\pgfdeclareshape{internalstorage}{
  \setpaths{\internalStorageAnchorPath}{\internalStorageBackgroundPath}
  \savedanchor{\northeast}{
    \pgf@x = \ctbnex
    \mincorrect{\pgf@x}{\pgfshapeminwidth}
    \advance\pgf@x\pgfshapeouterxsep
    \pgf@y = \ctbney
    \mincorrect{\pgf@y}{\pgfshapeminheight}
    \advance\pgf@y\pgfshapeouterysep
  }
  \anchor{south east}{\northeast \pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
  \anchor{south}{\northeast \pgf@x=0pt \pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
  \anchor{south west}{\northeast \pgf@x=-\pgf@x \pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
  \anchor{west}{\northeast \pgf@x=-\pgf@x \pgf@y=0pt}
  \anchor{north west}{\northeast \pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
  \anchor{north}{\northeast \pgf@x=0pt}
  \anchor{north east}{\northeast}
  \anchor{east}{\northeast \pgf@y=0pt}
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    >=stealth,
    every state/.style={
      font=\small,
      blur shadow,
      thick,
    },
    every edge/.append style={
      ->,
      thick,
    },
    process/.style={
      state,
      rectangle,
      text width=10em,
      text centered,
      rounded corners,
      top color=orange!60,
      bottom color=orange!20,
    },
    internal storage/.style={
      state,
      internalstorage,
      draw=none,
      blur shadow={
        shadow opacity=0
      },
      font=\small,
      text width=5em,
      text centered,
      append after command={
        \pgfextra{
          \draw[
            thick,
            blur shadow,
            top color=BlueViolet!60,
            bottom color=BlueViolet!20
          ]  (\tikzlastnode.south east)
          -- ( $(\tikzlastnode.south west) + (-\padding, 0)$ )
          -- ( $(\tikzlastnode.north west) + (-\padding, \padding)$ )
          -- ( $(\tikzlastnode.north east) + (0, \padding)$ )
          -- cycle;
          \draw[thick] ( $(\tikzlastnode.north west) + (-\padding, 0)$ )
                    -- (\tikzlastnode.north east);
          \draw[thick] ( $(\tikzlastnode.north west) + (0, \padding)$ )
                    -- (\tikzlastnode.south west);
        }
      },
    },
  ]
  \matrix (m)[matrix of nodes, column sep=8mm, row sep=6.5mm, align=center, nodes={rectangle, draw, anchor=center}]{
    |[process]| {north west} & |[process]|          {north           } & |[process]| {north east} \\
    |[process]| {west      } & |[internal storage]| {Internal Storage} & |[process]| {east      } \\
    |[process]| {south west} & |[process]|          {south           } & |[process]| {south east} \\
  };
  \draw (m-1-1) edge (m-2-2);
  \draw (m-1-2) edge (m-2-2);
  \draw (m-1-3) edge (m-2-2);
  \draw (m-2-3) edge (m-2-2);
  \draw (m-3-3) edge (m-2-2);
  \draw (m-3-2) edge (m-2-2);
  \draw (m-3-1) edge (m-2-2);
  \draw (m-2-1) edge (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```